# Optional operator overloading within a template in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17

I have a small wrapper class around `std::optional<T>`. Let's call it `MaybeValue<T>`.
My goal is to be able to use standard operators (like `+`, `*`, `<`, …) on the underlying types iff both objects are not "empty" :

```cpp
MaybeValue<int> v1 = 1;
MaybeValue<int> v2 = {};

assert(v1 + v2 == {});
assert(v1 + 1 == MaybeValue<int>(2));
```

I've tried to overload the method `MaybeValue<T>::operator+`, but then `T` is required to implement `operator+`. That is not what I want, because I would like use `MaybeValue<T>` with types that do not implement the `+` operator but implement other operators, like `<`.

Is it possible to overload an operator only if it exists on the underlying type?

Comment: Please show a [mre] with what you have tried and the error you've received. You should be able to implement all the operators regardless of the support of the underlying types, you'll only get an error if you actually try to call the operators

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to overload the method MaybeValue::operator+, but then T is required to implement operator+. That is not what I want, because I would like use MaybeValue with types that do not implement the + operator but implement other operators, like <.

One option is to not do anything. With implicit instantiation, a method of a class template is only instantiated if it is called; ["unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). (However if the class is explicitly instantiated, e.g. `template class MaybeValue<int>;`, then everything in the class is instantiated.) If T does not support +, then using `MaybeValue<T>` is fine so long as `MaybeValue<T>::operator+` is never called. If the operator *is* called, then a compile error pops up complaining about `MaybeValue<T>::operator+` as well as the offending calling code that instantiated it, so you know what needs to be fixed.

But if you want more intentionally to disable the unsupported operations, the standard solution to defining a function conditionally based on type is [SFINAE or "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). A good tool for this is [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or (since C++17) [std::void_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t). For instance, this example from the std::enable_if page defines a "construct" function, but only for T that is trivially constructible:

```
// #1, enabled via the return type
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>::value>::type 
    construct(T*) 
{
    std::cout << "default constructing trivially default constructible T\n";
}
```

Comment: What if the args aren't trivially constructible but initialized.

Comment: SFINAE happens at compile time, so whether args are initialized doesn't matter. The condition given to std::enable_if is any predicate that can be evaluated at compile time. You can replace the "std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>" with "std::is_arithmetic<T>" or "std::is_trivially_copyable<T>" or any other static predicate about T. Check out the [type_traits library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) for some standard ones.

Comment: I know that. I just wanted to mention that is_trivially_conatructible is not appropriate here

Comment: Yes, the easiest solution is the "not do anything" option of just not calling unsupported operators to avoid instantiating them. I mention SFINAE as a side remark, so I'll leave it as an illustrative example of std::enable_if as a starting point. If anyone would like to flesh out SFINAE for this case, that's great.